# Stored procedure error A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that was working perfectly and suddenly without any updates it stopped, and I got this massage. I tried everything I could get or know and nothing

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CreateFileAsmoFormat, Line 0
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "CreateFileAsmoFormat": 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(Object Prompt, MsgBoxStyle Buttons, Object Title)
>   at DataTransformer.Tools.SaveToFileAsmoFormat(String content, String filePath, Boolean IsAppend)

the code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO 
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFileAsmoFormat] 
 @FileNameWithPath [nvarchar](4000), 
 @FileData [nvarchar](4000), 
 @IsAppend [bit] 
 WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME [DataTransformer].
 [DataTransformer.ExecutionStoredProcedure]‌​.[CreateFileAsmoForm‌​at] 
GO
```

Comment: Try google exception itself. I did, and from what I learned, you could try updating .NET framework. I encourage you to do own research.

Comment: Possibly file not exist `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Check also .Net Framework installed 32/64.

Comment: Okay, something is going very wrong when you have a CLR object installed in SQL Server that has a dependency on `System.Windows.Forms`. You're trying to display a *message box* from within a *server* that likely *doesn't have anybody logged in interactively to it*. Since we can't see your code and don't know why you were trying to display a message box, we're not going to be able to provide much assistance here.

Comment: How do you expect us to help fix problems in the code we can't see? We are developers, not mind readers...

Comment: @ZoharPeled 

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFileAsmoFormat]
 FileNameWithPath [nvarchar](4000),
 FileData [nvarchar](4000),
 IsAppend [bit]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [DataTransformer].[DataTransformer.ExecutionStoredProcedure].[CreateFileAsmoFormat]
GO

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: Yeah, but no. The code throwing an error is *.NET code* we need to see the .NET code that *implements* `CreateFileAsmoForm‌​at`. Not the SQL that installs it.